# Javascript: Date().toJSON() changes date

Tags: javascript, date-format, to-json

```
> new Date().toJSON() =  "2013-11-21T03:58:17.178Z"

>new Date() = Wed Nov 20 2013 19:58:20 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Why changing the representation changes the date format?

Comment: It gives GMT, add 8 hrs to your date.

Answer (score 1):

JSON dates have the same format as the ISO-8601 standard, which is by default expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), and Date() is expressed as your local time.